# What causes me to be unable to burn Windows 7 ISO due to a medium error?

Tags: disk-utility, dvd-burning, iso

I've just upgraded my 2011 17" MacBook Pro with a brand spankin' new SSD hard drive and 8GB of RAM. In order to fully maximize the potential of the system, I'd like to install Windows 7 to take full advantage of the specs.

That being said, when I downloaded the [Windows 7 ISO](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/) from Digital River, I was unable to burn it through Disk Utility. The burn failed due to a medium error, and I can't figure out why.

It's a brand new spindle of DVD-Rs, granted it's a brand I've never heard of, but I was able to burn a couple other items using them, so I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try more than once?

Comment: Yes. I tried more than once with several different discs, and it always ended up with the same results.

Comment: Which brand? Did you try other bootable images? I once used a Chinese brand which could burn everything except bootable disks fine.

Comment: The brand name escapes me at the moment (as I said, it was a brand I've never encountered before). And no, I didn't try any other bootable images for lack of need of any other bootable images.

Comment: If that’s the case, then I highly recommend trying to burn another bootable image, for it will reveal whether the DVD-R is to blame for the mess you have got yourself in.

Comment: A valid suggestion. I'll give it a shot with an Ubuntu image when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was the oddball brand (Ativa) causing the issues. Bought a spindle of Maxell discs and it's burning like a charm.